# Merging two or more images in WP 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, writeablebitmapex, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm trying to create a bigger image by repeated tiling multiple small images. How can I do this in C# / WP8.1?

I've tried to merge byte arrays (simple appending doesn't work), tried to render on XAML (doesn't work, get separation lines with some images), tried with WriteableBitmapEx (too slow, requires UI thread for processing) and two methods of Lumia Imaging SDK (JpegTools and BlendEffect) but both produce separation lines.

With that said, is there any other method available that can be used to merge two or more images?

I'd like to explore the option of byte level copying; how do I go about it? How do I merge two image arrays and create a single larger image?

**EDIT:** The question is for WP 8.1 RT and not generic C# platform.

Comment: Have you looked into Emgu (OpenCV .Net wrapper)? Its fairly easy (and fast) to load an image given a path and loop over it as a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WriteableBitmapEx to load the original image into a WB, then use WriteableBitmapEx to get access to the buffer / Pixels property and run the merging in a background thread. So get the Pixels array of all the WBs you want to merge and then use the Pixels array and merge those. You might even be able to use a quick Buffer.BlockCopy or its equivalent on WinRT. 
Once you have the finally merged array buffer, create a new WB with the right aggregated dimension and set its Pixels buffer to the merged array.
You only need to access the UI thread when you instantiate a new WB.

Comment: I used `WriteableBitmapEx.Blit()` to repeatedly merge the images, but `Blit()` method requires UI thread too. Also, I didn't quite get how to merge images using the byte buffer. Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: OK, I added some more detail. You won't have to use the Blit() at all. Just use WBX to get the Pixels buffer of the original images in a more easy way, merge the Pixels buffers manually and then create a new WB based on that.